# Flex code to convert '1.4348907E22' to '14348907000000000000000'

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3

I am trying to convert Double format number `'1.4348907E22'` to String format `'14348907000000000000000'`

I didn't found any clue over the internet for it, can somebody help me on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `mx.formatters.NumberFormatter` like this:

```
var fmt:NumberFormatter = new NumberFormatter();
fmt.useThousandsSeparator = false;
trace(fmt.format('1.4348907E22'));
```

This outputs `14348907000000000000000` to the console.

Comment: Thanks @splash, Worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 Double d = Double.parseDouble("1.4348907E22");
 String s = String.format("%.0f", d);

 // just for controlling purposes
 System.out.println(s);
```

it outputs: 14348907000000000000000

Comment: you have writter java code, I have even better way to do that like this,
**new DecimalFormat("0").format(number)**

But I am looking for Flex code.